# `rot90` not working as expected for image rotation in Matlab.

Tags: image, matlab, rotation, image-rotation

**IMAGE1**

[image]

**IMAGE2**

[image]

**DESIRED IMAGE**

[image]

I am using function `flipud` and `rot90` to rotate **IMAGE1** to look like **IMAGE2** as following:

```
IMAGE2=rot90(flipud(IMAGE1));
```

However, somehow I do not get the desired result which is **DESIRED IMAGE**. Could anyone identify why? Please ignore the side legend cutout in **DESIRED IMAGE**.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought was the actual result.  So what is the actual result?

Comment: My bad. I have corrected the variable names and clarified the question's structure.

Comment: I was adding data for `IMAGE1` but I couldn't add because it was exceeding the words limit of a question. If you require data then let me know.

Comment: It's still not clear.  You've given us the original input and the desired output, but not the actual output.  So it's difficult to identify what the problem is!

Comment: Oh, ok. I've added the actual output plus I have edited the names of the images accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for a 2D array (see comments)

```
%# create a 2D array (3x3, but it'll work for 50x50 as well)
m = magic(3)
m =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

%# flip, then rotate, but rotate clockwise, hence the -1
rot90(flipud(m),-1)
ans =
     8     3     4
     1     5     9
     6     7     2

%# Note that this is the same as taking the transpose
m'
ans =
     8     3     4
     1     5     9
     6     7     2
```

Comment: Hi Jonas: I have 2D data instead of image which I use to plot **IMAGE1**. As presented in the question, I am applying `IMAGE2=rot90(flipud(IMAGE1));` on 2D *data* of **IMAGE1**. I tried your steps i.e. to `rot90()` first and then `flipud()`, however that doesn't seems to work. What would you suggest in that case?

Comment: @S_H: Did you exactly follow what I did? I.e. rotate in the other direction (that's what the -1 stands for)? The order is not important, so you could also have flipped first and rotated later.

Comment: I know. But it's not working and I am not sure why. I am using data to rotate and then plot.

Comment: Can you re-write it in form of `50x50` 2D data than in form of image?

Comment: @S_H: I have rewritten it for a 3x3 2D array. All the commands will work for a 50x50 array as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but apparently something weird is going on which is why I am not getting correct result. Even after doing exactly as you suggested I am getting the result as shown under **OUTPUT IMAGE** in the **UPDATE**. Please see above. I have also included the code lines I am using on my variable just above the **OUTPUT IMAGE**.

Comment: @S_H: If you apply the exact same commands as you posted once more, do you get the original image? If yes, then there is really something weird going on. Normally, applying this transformation twice should be equivalent to doing nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by **original image**? I am using commands which I posted above under **UPDATE** just once and then I am plotting. The plot that I get finally is shown under **OUTPUT IMAGE**.

Comment: @S_H: I understand. Now please execute the same two lines one more time and look at the image that is now shown. Is it the same as **ORIGINAL IMAGE**?

Comment: I executed the first line (`%# flip and rotate`) one more time (in total two times). The final image obtained does not look any of the four images shown above. Please see in the question under **UPDATE 2** to see how it looks like. Thanks.

Comment: @S_H: The image in UPDATE2 looks exactly like the transpose. If you execute the flip and rotate one more time, I bet you will end up with the UPDATE image. This suggests that the array you've originally applied the transformation to is *not* what is shown in ORIGINAL IMAGE.

Comment: What do you mean by ORIGINAL IMAGE? Do you mean IMAGE1?

Comment: If I flip and rotate one more time I do not end up with UPDATE image. Rather, I get an image exactly as under UPDATE2. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @S_H: You must have something very weird going on. Applying the transpose operation twice should bring you back to the array you started with.

Comment: You are right my ORIGINAL IMAGE (IMAGE1) as shown is not what it looks like if I plot it. Thanks for that heads up.